# ios - Set environment of a target based on the running target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, target, compiler-flags

I have an iOS project with theses targets:

```
- MyTargetUAT 
- MyTargetPreprod
- MyCustomFramework 
    - EmbeddedFrameworkUAT 
    - EmbeddedFrameworkPreprod
```

My goal is, when I build MyTargetUAT, to tell MyCustomFramework to use the EmbeddedFrameworkUAT.

How is it possible for MyCustomFramework to know which environment is set at runtime ?

NB: Everytime I build my app, MyCustomFramework is recompiled and generates a new MyCustomFramework.framework

Answer (score 0):

In default, your targets have different **Info.plist** files. Maybe you can add a variable to this file to detect which target you are using or your **Info.plist** file already contains some target-specific values (like Bundle ID). You can use these values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But is it possible to access a plist which is not in my target ? 
How can you do it ?

Comment: You set info.plist file in Build settings of your targets. If you set relevant .plist file to target you can parse it in your code and see inside. You don't need to add the file to your target. Or you can use two different .plist files from Info.plist (for just these configs) and and parse in your code. But this time, you may need to add this files to relevant targets.

Comment: You can look here for detailed usage https://www.appcoda.com/xcconfig-guide/ It is also used xcodeconfig files too. This is a better practice than I mention

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use building phrase scripts. First you need a config file in your MyCustomFramework target, your target read the configuration file to decide which embedded framework to use. Then in your MyTargetUAT target building phrase, add a script to modify the config file in your MyCustomFramework target. So when you build MyTargetUAT target, the script file get executed, and update your config for MyCustomFramework target.

Comment: Yes but how MyCustomFramework will determine if it is MyTargetUAT or MyTargetPreprod that is currently running ?

Comment: @UgoMarinelli Running? What do mean by Running? Do You mean your MyCustomFramework target code is executing or code get compiling and linking?  You wanna replace your code dynamically?

Comment: When my app is compiling, it will everytime rebuild MyCustomFramework, I want to run a script to select the good embedded framework based on the target (MyTargetUAT or MyTargetPreprod)

Comment: OK, I see! So write a building phrase for your MyCustomFramework target to read the config file in according to edit your building environment, like framework paths, add the right embedded framework file path to it.  Then you’re all done.